# Cassandra: error when querying based on a value in a set collection

Tags: cassandra, cql

I've got a table called `place_ratings` with column headers `rating_id`, `place_id`, `place_name`, `place_rating`, and `cuisines`.

The primary key is `rating_id` and it is an integer.

`place_id` is an integer, as is `place_rating`.

`place_name` is of type text.

`cuisines` is a set collection of type text.

Sample data for one row in the table is as follows:

`rating_id` = 5

`place_id` = 658

`place_name` = 'Bobbys Burgers'

`place_rating` = 10

`cuisines` = { 'Burgers', 'Chips', 'Milkshakes' }

I am trying to write a query to return all of the rows where the cuisine is 'Pizzeria' only.

This is my code:

`SELECT place_id, place_name, place_rating FROM place_ratings WHERE cuisines = { 'Pizzeria' };`

However, I get the following error message:

`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Collection column 'cuisines' (set<text>) cannot be restricted by a '=' relation"`

What changes do I need to make to my code to get my query to run correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a secondary index for that column, and then search using this index (see [documentation for more information](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useIndexColl.html)):

```
CREATE INDEX cousine_idx ON place_ratings ( cuisines );
SELECT * FROM place_ratings WHERE cuisines CONTAINS 'Pizzeria';
```

But usually such queries aren't the good fit for Cassandra as they require the scanning of data on all nodes to find the actual rows containing the data - because you didn't provide the partition key.  Although if you'll add a restriction on partition key, for example, search for pizzerias in specific city, then it will work better.